# Retrieve only the execution status of the StoredProcedure (Spring)

Tags: spring, stored-procedures, db2, resultset

rephrasing my question:
Is there a way the execute method of org.springframework.jdbc.object.StoredProcedure would provide the return code when the stored procedure does not return a resultset (via a open cursor) but returns just the status code?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the GET DIAGNOSTICS statement (DB2_RETURN_STATUS): http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v10r5/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0005647.html

There are restrictions to use it, so you probably cannot execute it from Java. The best is to create a wrapper for the stored procedure.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE P1 ()
  BEGIN
   RETURN -1;
  END @

 CREATE PROCEDURE WRAPPER_P1(OUT RETURN_CODE INTEGER)
  BEGIN
   CALL PROCEDURE P1();
   GET DIAGNOSTIC RETURN_CODE = DB2_RETURN_STATUS;
  END @
```

And then just ask for the output value.

However, you should check the Spring Framework documentation for anything that extract this information from the sqlca. Or in the DB2 Java driver documentation.